# Чередование гласных в корне

Tags: орфография

Всем привет. Такой вопрос, существует чередование А(Я)/ИМ/ЕМ и А(Я)/ИН. Например взИМать - взЯть или сжИМать - сжАть.
И приводят пример, что слово "имущество", "имущественный" или "неимоверный" имеет чередующуюся гласную по этому правилу.
Вопрос, так ли это, и какое чередование можно подобрать этим словам?

Comment: Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста. Зачем что-то "подбирать", если вы уже признали наличие чередования? И о каком-таком правиле вы речь ведете?

Answer (score 1):

Я, хоть и не понял вопрос, попытаюсь ответить.

Слово ***"имущество"*** - очевидно однокоренное со словом "иметь" (обладать). Взимать - получать в имение (обладание). Ну а "взимать", как вы сами признаете, связано  корневым чередованием (Я/ИМ) с "взять". Что еще нужно-то?

С ***неимоверным*** - чуть сложнее. Но только потому, что исходное значение "не имеющий доверия" (т.е. невозможный) подзабылось. Но если сообразить, что общим понятием и тут является "иметь", "обладать", то все сразу проясняется.

Это достаточно для признания того, что и тут имеет место то же чередование.

***Сжимать-сжать*** - это тоже чередование, но другое, у этого корня нет общего значения с "иметь".

Что касается упоминаемого вами чередования (я/ин), то я просто затрудняюсь комментировать абстрактно, нужны примеры.

Answer (score 1):

Я не согласна с тем, что в слове имущество есть чередующийся корень. В словах взимать-взять корни взима- и взя- согласно словарю Тихонова. Образованы они от "иметь", праслав. *jьmǫ, но произошло опрощение основы и приставка срослась с корнем. Это не связанный корень (ним/ня - отнять, принять). Слова взимать и имущество уже не однокоренные, и если в паре взимать-взять есть чередование, то имущество уже стоит совершенно отдельно, корень имуществ-. Это исторически родственные слова.